# SQL to remove duplicate records without a distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

This is for Oracle DB SQL (pl/sql)

I have a three column data table (for sake of argument).
I need to removed the rows returned where columnA and columnB match another record in the table and columnC is equal to 'james'.  But if columnC equals 'james' and columnA,columnB do not match any other row in the result set keep it.

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
_______________________
45      blue    John   <-Keep
45      blue    James  <-Remove
32      Red     John   <-Keep
32      Red     James  <-Remove
12      Yellow  James  <-Keep
```

The result set would then be:

```
 ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
 _______________________
 45      blue    John
 32      Red     John
 12      Yellow  James
```

Obviously the real data is more complicated and there are more columns.  My background is in the C# side of the equation and not the Oracle DB side. I have tried some temp tables but I could not get anything close to work since I need to have something that says "I returned more that one row and one of them is a james record".  Thanks for the help.

Comment: what if there are multiple row with 45, blue and other names?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh  for this example I just want to remove the James record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using a window function to get the count of matching records:

```
SELECT
    columnA,
    columnB,
    columnC
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            columnA,
            columnB,
            columnC,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY columnA, columnB) as rcount
        FROM table
    ) sub
WHERE 
    (sub.rcount = 2 AND columnC = 'John')
    OR sub.rcount = 1;
```

Comment: This answer is way too specific. It won't work on slightly more data.

Comment: I was able to implement this for demoing but other issues with doing it at this layer (DB vs View) has me moving to a different solution (ie this is only a small part of a large procedure that we don't want to retest).  But this is adds another tool to my toolbox.  Thanks

Comment: @GurwinderSingh This answer is specific to the question. The big take-away for OP is that grabbing a COUNT(*) over a partition will allow them to discover duplicate records by that partition. What they wish to filter after discovering that is up to them. Perhaps `WHERE sub.rcount > 1 AND columnC <> 'James'`, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if there are non-"James" records for the given combination of columnA and columnB using analytic `count` function with `case`:

```
with your_table (ColumnA ,ColumnB ,ColumnC) as (
    select 45, 'blue'    ,'ABC'  from dual union all
    select 45, 'blue'    ,'Jimmy'  from dual union all
    select 45, 'blue'    ,'John'  from dual union all
    select 45, 'blue'    ,'James' from dual union all 
    select 32, 'Red'     ,'John'  from dual union all 
    select 32, 'Red'     ,'James' from dual union all 
    select 12, 'Yellow'  ,'James' from dual
    )
--Sample data ends. Solution starts below--


select ColumnA ,ColumnB ,ColumnC
from (
    select t.*,
        case when count(case when columnC <> 'James' then 1 end) over (
                    partition by columnA,
                    columnB
                    ) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as flag
    from your_table t
    )
where flag = 0
    or columnC <> 'James'
```

Output:

```
COLUMNA COLUMNB COLUMNC
12      Yellow  James
32      Red     John
45      blue    John
45      blue    Jimmy
45      blue    ABC
```